# Is there any way I can check if FTP server is running on a particular server?

Tags: windows, ftp

How to check if `ftp server` is running on a particular server ? For example I want to know if there is *ftp server* running for the IP `xxx.xxx.xxx.xx`.

Is there any way I can get the information ? Name of the web-server on which the website is running is *Microsoft-IIS/6.0* and OS is *Windows Server 2003*

Though I don't have FTP server running locally, but I get a FTP prompt :

```
C:\Users\user>ftp 127.0.0.1
ftp>
```

Answer (score 6):

Are you trying to establish whether the ftp server is running on a machine to which you have access? If so, what you just did,

```
ftp localhost
```

, is perfect: you do have an ftp server running. You might have established the same point by checking running processes with Task manager or any other such utility, but the route you chose is even better, in a way, because it tells you it is not only running but also functioning properly.

By the same token, typing

```
ftp Some.New.Ip.Address
```

works also for a possible ftp server running on a machine to which you do not have access. If there were no ftp server running, you would get the reply:

```
ftp: connect: Connection refused
```

or something similar.

This assumes that the server is using the standard ftp port 21. If for any reason, the person who set up the ftp server is a bit secretive, he/she may have moved the listening port to some non-standard port. In this case, barring a direct question to the site manager, your best hope is with a sophisticated instrument like 
**nmap**, which is capable of identifying the non-standard port on which the server might be listening.

Comment: I want to check if `ftp` server is running on ip `xxx...` or not. How do I check that ?

Comment: ftp xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Comment: and how do I know if I am connected to the server ? As I enter `ftp xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` , I see a ftp prompt but I am not sure if I am connected because as I enter the command `LIST`, it says `invalid command`.I must mention that I didn't enter any `username` or `passoword` to connect to that ip

Comment: Like I said above, if there is no ftp server you will get a reply like ftp: connect: connection refused. If you get a prompt, it means there is a sever, you may not be authenticated, but the server has already replied, thus it exists.

Comment: okay but why do I get _ftp prompt_ when I do `ftp localhost` because I am not running ftp server on my machine

Comment: try the command ps ax | grep ftp

Comment: What is it for ? I tried..but what is it for ?

Answer (score 2):

`ftp site.ip.address` is a simple and decent way, however I would suggest you use [nmap](http://nmap.org/) as it can scan through all the ports for you. If ftp is not running on port 21, you will at least know what other ports are open.

Answer (score 2):

You can do `telnet` towards the FTP server
`telnet FTP_server_ip port`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
service vsftpd status
```

Comment: question mentions about windows ...